# How do I change the command that a launcher item launches?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

I'm not sure what commands are issued when trying to launch a program from the dash.  How can I determine this and modify the commands of these short cuts?

For example, I would like to change the command to launch skype from:

```
skype
```

to

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

I'm not sure which command is issued when I click on the icon in the dash and I'm not sure how I would change it.  Changing it using gnome menu editor does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I couldn't find the shortcuts, we can use the `.local/share/applications` folder.

You can create a file this way:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/myskype.desktop
```

Then paste something like this into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Version=1.0
Name=My Skype
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so" skype
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=skype
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;
StartupWMClass=Skype
StartupNotify=true
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so" skype
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Save and exit.

Comment: Sorry. Perhaps I didn't explain myself properly.  I want to change the command for a particular program that I launch from the dash.  I've adjusted my original question accordingly.

Comment: @desgua, thanks for your quick replies!  As I understand it, the dash is the interface that appears when you hit the super key... not the unity side bar thing.

Comment: I'm very sorry for that. You are absolutely right.

Comment: No worries.  I appreciate your help regardless!

Comment: @desgua Copy the .desktop into .local/share/applications like we do on the other quicklist questions, otherwise an upgrade will overwrite his customizations.

Comment: @Jorge Castro thank you so much for this very important advice.

Comment: @desgua, thanks for your help! I changed the exec line to the following, and accepted your answer: exec=env LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so" skype. The env command is required to get it to launch properly.

Comment: @astjohn thank you for fixing it. I'm glad we got it. ;-)

Comment: @desgua Thank you for `StartupWMClass=Skype` and `StartupNotify=true`!! These make Unity work like an unconfused charm :)

Comment: @CetinSert Welcome ;-)

Comment: Here's a supporting link: http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/384

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you can edit the file **/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop** Make a backup copy first. You probably need to edit the line that reads **Exec=skype** to include the changes you want.

[Edit] Just tried this for myself and the syntax for .desktop files doesn't allow the **=** sign in the Exec command so you may need to create a shell script with your command in and point the Exec line at that.

Here is some background about the .desktop files:
http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It's because you need the env command.  Please refer to my last comment directed to desgua.  I'm going to give the answer to him because of his quick response and patience.  Cheers.

Comment: @astjohn: this is actually the correct answer, because it explains where to find the shortcuts for the items in the launcher. Desgua's answer creates a new shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: Copying a .desktop file and modifying details works, but with some caveats... for example, trying to launch `wine foobar2000.exe` results in two launcher icons, and none of them pick up the icon from foobar2000.exe.