# Is there a quick easy way to access the command line for unity launchers?

Tags: command-line, appmenu, unity

I'd like to be able to access the command that is executed by launchers in Unity in a quick and easy way - something like a right-click entry.

There are answers that are a bit more involved [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23272/is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-to-launch-any-program-from-the-command-line) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39205/how-do-i-change-the-command-that-a-launcher-item-launches). I'd like to be able to access the command line faster and without having to remember how (beyond, say, right clicking).

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood the question, but can't you use a keyboard shortcut to get there?
i.e. Open gnome-keybinding-properties, find an unattributed key combination, click on Add, give your shortcut a name, type gnome-terminal as the command to invoke, and that's about it.

Comment: thats not really what I'm after. Among other things, I want to know the name (and possibly location) of the executable. One use for this could be to use it on the command line with some chosen options (eg: -h to find out what options it has ;)  Another would be to find out what command line options/parameters the launcher is using

Comment: Again, not sure this is the right answer, but the executable is just gnome-terminal, isn't it? and the path /usr/bin/gnome-terminal To find the location of an application: whereis gnome-terminal. I'm not using Unity myself, as I find the classic ubuntu look easier to configure and prettier all round, so I may still be missing the point!

Comment: I think I understand now. You said you wanted to access the command line, but I think you just mean the command itself. You'll find all the desktop launcher files in /usr/share/applications where they all have a .desktop suffix. If you open them up with a text editor like gedit, you should see the command Unity uses on the line "Exec", with options, i.e. Exec=ego %U. You can modify this or add new launchers, following the model. A long way from a right-click, I'm afraid, but I think that if you like configuring your desktop, the classic look is best for you! Hope this helps.

Comment: yep, that's one of the more involved answers given in the links I included in the question.. I'm after something easier to remember and quicker (: